# UIView under UINavigationBar on IOS7

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uirefreshcontrol

We're working on the transition between IOS6 and IOS7 and have the next issues, for the moment without solution:

The structure of our view is the next one:

1. UIView
2. UIToolbar for ad-hoc buttons (filter button for the list)
3. UISearchBar over the UIToolbar to integrate the search component with the list
4. UITableView

Working perfectly on the previous versions of the IOS SDK.

But in IOS7 we have the next troubles:

1. The UIToolbar and UISearch bar is not visible anymore
2. We integrated the UIRefreshBar component and after refresh the UITableView always move under the UINavigationBar

Any suggestions?

Comment: Applications/OS being discussed are under NDA. You should ask this question in devforums.apple.com.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regarding
1.The `UIToolbar` and `UISearchBar` is not visible any more write the below code in `viewDidLoad` and your problem will solved.

```
[self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIExtendedEdgeLeft | 
                                UIExtendedEdgeBottom | 
                                UIExtendedEdgeRight];
```

Comment: In fact, this line is good :

        [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeLeft | UIRectEdgeBottom | UIRectEdgeRight];

Comment: In Interface Builder, if you click on a UIViewController there is a set of checkboxes under name "Extend Edges" behaving exactly the same.

Answer (score 15):

1. In `viewDidLoad` this worked for me

   [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
2. If you like storyboard, select the `viewController` and make sure `Extended Edges` >> `Under top bars` is not selected.

[image]

---

**Update:**
For people like me, who can't install Xcode 5 available only in Mountain Lion:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 70000
    [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding
2. We integrated the UIRefreshBar component and after refresh the UITableView always move under the UINavigationBar

Make the NavigationBar not translucent, by default it is which allows views to scroll underneath it.