# Navigation bar overlapping my content after show Segue

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller with a table view and a tab bar controller. I perform a segue when one of the cells is tapped in the `didSelectRow` method. I then pass the data in `prepareForSegue`. The segue is set up in the storyboard from the view controller to the tab bar and its kind is "Show".

When the tab bar controller is displayed (well, one of its view controllers), the content is at the very top of the view. The problem is fixed after I switch tab bars and then go back to the original tab bar. Any way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you using Storyboards for this view controller?

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed Yes, I am!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIView under UINavigationBar on IOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745571/uiview-under-uinavigationbar-on-ios7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using interface builder?

Open storyboard where you defined this view controller.

Then in Attributes Inspector **DESELECT** the `Extend Edges Under Top Bars` property.

Alternatively you can make your view snap to the Top Layout Guide instead of the root view itself.